# Can't edit tags on merged questions

Tags: feature-request, tags, edits, merged-questions

I was about to edit out the tag [body](/questions/tagged/body) on this question (body is a useless tag, should almost always be HTML, most questions are asking about the BODY tag in HTML)

[How to stick the document's border to the bottom?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6243090/how-to-stick-the-documents-border-to-the-bottom)

However, I don't have the ability to edit merged questions. Is this by design? I have permission to edit normal questions.

Comment: We just wiped out the body tag!  Thanks for your help =)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The question you linked to has been closed over 6 months.

Once it gets merged, the original question exists for historical purposes only and cannot be edited.

Comment: Does that mean bad tags are frozen in time forever?

Comment: @Incognito No, moderators can still edit or remove them.  Feel free to flag posts like the one you linked to that are preventing bad tags from being wiped out. (The `body` tag is no more.)

Comment: Thanks @BilltheLizard.  That was the last of the [body] tags!  Now on to the other useless html-element tags (at some point) =)

Comment: I know this is meta, but what is helpful here (gives the solution) is Bill's comment. The content of this answer post just states the obvious.