# Allow Trusted Users to edit merge stubs

Tags: feature-request, edits, privileges, merged-questions

I'd like to have [Trusted Users](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/trusted-user) (at 20,000 Reputation) granted another edit power: the ability to **edit** (or **suggest edits** to) **merge stubs** in circumstances where it would be beneficial (instead of having to flag a moderator for an edit).

Considerations:

- Merging a post is done because it is an exact duplicate in case it has good answers that would be beneficial on the target, so there is generally no contraindication to allow fixing broken links/images/formatting/spelling on those.
- There is already an existing concern from users regarding fixing tags on merged posts: [Can't edit tags on merged questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/117789/cant-edit-tags-on-merged-questions)
- Trusted users are already granted an edit privilege encompassing an even bigger responsibility: editing tag wikis without needing approval. So they should be allowed to edit merged posts too.
- There are multiple ways to implement this feature (*edits* or *suggest edits*). If it is implemented as *suggested edits*, then those suggested edits could be reviewed by other Trusted Users.

Comment: Are you saying you can't edit things on the question they were merged *to*?

Comment: @JonClements merged _from_.

Comment: @JonClements example where I had to flag a moderator to suggest an edit: [How can I stop browsers from caching my website? (if the cache really is the issue)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9738613/how-can-i-stop-browsers-from-caching-my-website-if-the-cache-really-is-the-iss). I feel sorry to have bothered a moderator for that.

Comment: How many merged questions are there? I've merged 6 it appears in the 3 and a bit years as an SO mod... since the quantities are going to be tiny, and the fact that merging locks the source question (that's why it prevents non-mod editing) - I'm wondering if the dev. time to implement this is worth it just 
 to avoid raising the occasional custom flag and explaining why you can't edit it (and including a link to a gist with the mark down it should have or something?)

Comment: @JonClements then maybe suggest to extend the Trusted User edit privilege to all locked posts, to make it worth the dev time? Here is an example of locked post where I had to flag a moderator to suggest an edit: [What is the best way to programmatically detect porn images?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/713247/what-is-the-best-way-to-programmatically-detect-porn-images)

Comment: That'd make it a bit more worthwhile - but sadly there's a fair amount of trusted users that butt heads over post edits and in that case - you don't want them overriding a locked post...

Comment: @JonClements Makes sense. Another idea: make merged posts just "closed as duplicate" instead of "locked"+"closed as duplicate". That will grant everybody the edit privilege on those, while still merging the answers.

Comment: I imagine why that route wasn't chosen is that people could then vote to reopen the post and you end up with possible answers again and no sign post... Ideally, a mod should clear up the source question before merging and ideally it should then never really need to be touched (except rare cases - maybe to allow tag burns to go through etc...)...

Comment: I've had some flags on merge stubs asking for tag edits where the moderator chose to delete the merge stub instead, as they considered it not helpful.